# eval in shell script - purpose of \${value}

Tags: shell, eval, readfile

I have inherited a shell script which has following code

```
while IFS='=' read -r key value
do
  # echo "key ${key}"
  if [[ ${key} =~ ^# ]]; then
    # echo "comment line ${key},  skipping....."
    continue
  fi
  eval ${key}=\${value}
  echo "key: ${key}, value: ${value}"
done <kafka-parameters.txt
```

where kafka-parameters.txt file contains entries like below

```
#Schema Registry
DEV_SR_URLS=http://sr1-dev:8081, http://sr2-dev:8081
QA_SR_URLS=http://sr1-qa:8081, http://sr2-qa:8081
STAGE_SR_URLS=http://sr1-qa:8081, http://sr2-qa:8081
PROD_SR_URLS=http://sr1:8081, http://sr2:8081
#
#Bootstrap Servers
DEV_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=broker1-dev:9092,broker2-dev:9092,broker3-dev:9092
QA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=broker1-qa:9092,broker2-qa:9092,broker3-qa:9092
STAGE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=broker1-qa:9092,broker2-qa:9092,broker3-qa:9092
PROD_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=broker1:9092,broker2:9092,broker3:9092
#
```

In the above snippet, what is the purpose of "\" before ${value} ?

From my understanding `eval ${key}=${value}` creates a variable of name ${key} and assigns value of ${value} to it and eval makes that assignment available after the loop.

Is this correct?  Still do not understand the purpose of \${value}

or what is difference between

```
eval ${key}=\${value}

and

eval ${key}=${value}
```

Comment: Often code like that is needed when eval is involved.  The \${value} delays the evaluation of ${value} until the eval statement is run.  Without the backslash, $value would have a constant value, throughout the script, set when the script was read.  With the backslash, ${value} is expanded at the time the eval is executed.

Comment: So, is this bash equivalent of how the delayedexpansion works in a windows batch script?  It seems to be so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following assignment:

```
value="foo bar"
key=$value
```

This will work, because the right-hand side doesn't undergo word-splitting; the name `key` will get the value `foo bar`.

Now consider

```
key=foo
$key=$value
```

This is just an error, because it's not an assignment; it's an attempt, after parameter expansion and word-splitting, to run a command name `foo=foo` with an argument `bar`.

Using `eval`, we choose to let some expansions happen *befor* `eval` runs, and some to happen after. With

```
eval $key=\${value}
```

`eval` will see the string `foo=${value}`, which it will execute by expanding `$value}` and assigning the entire result to `foo`, similar to the first example above.

However, if you let *both* parameters expand first,

```
eval $key=${value}
```

then after parameter expansion `eval` gets *two* arguments, `key=foo` and `bar`, which results in a command named `bar` being executed with `key=foo` in its environment.